# Python printing issue with space

Tags: python, printing

Hello I am currently working on something and I am trying to print output as such in python

> hello=10

but my code below is printing it as such

> hello= 10

10 is an int i have tried these codes but none work

```
print "hello=",10
print "hello=",str(10)
print "hello=",str(10).strip()
```

i would appreciate the help thank you

Comment: This is just a visual aspect of your code editor, it doesn't affect the functionality of what you are trying to do. Can you provide context on why you need this? you could just try `print "hello=10"`

Comment: The `,` forms a tuple which prints space separated. Instead use `print "hello=%s" % 10` or the more modern `'hello={0}'.format(10)`

Comment: That's exactly what's supposed to happen. When you pass multiple items to print it spaces them out. If you don't want that, build a single string you do want and pass that instead.

Comment: 10 is a passed down number from a loop i need this as a part of the visual aspects of my output

Comment: thank you Paul that worked!

Answer (score 3):

Simply concatenate the strings:

```
print "hello="+str(10)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format),

```
print("hello={}".format(10))
```

---

PS: The `print` statement has been replaced with a [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function since Python 3.0.

```
Old: print x,           # Trailing comma suppresses newline
New: print(x, end=" ")  # Appends a space instead of a newline
```

Refer to [Print Is A Function](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) for the detailed descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `print` with multiple arguments, separated by `,`, a single space `' '` is inserted as a separator in between each of those.

When using Python 3's [`print` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), you can specify the `sep` parameter; default is `' '`.

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function  # when in Python 2
>>> print("hello=", 10)
hello= 10
>>> print("hello=", 10, sep="")
hello=10
>>> print("hello=", 10, sep="###")
hello=###10
```

For Python 2's [`print` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print), there is to the best of my knowledge no such option.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using the Python 3 compatible `print()` function:

This function can be used after a `__future__` directive:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print("hello=", 10, sep='')
```

Output:

```
hello=10
```

The `print()` function as a *sep* keyword argument which allows you to replace the space separator by an empty string.

Here is the online help:

> Help on built-in function print in module builtins:
>
> print(...)
>       print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
>
> ```
> Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
> Optional keyword arguments:
> file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
> sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
> end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
> flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The call "print" will place a space for a comma.

Yes, Python provides many ways to print the strings as above mentioned, I still would like to construct the output with C or Java style format:

```
print "hello=%d" % 10
```